# How to create a header to list in android?

Tags: android

In my project I need to display a paragraph and questions(with options) on that paragraph. Each paragraph contains 7 to 8 questions. Now I have created a textview for displaying the paragraph and listview for displaying questions and options of that paragraph. The problem is when I am displaying the paragraph it is not showing the listview...i.e based on the content of the paragraph in the textview the listview is displaying with scroll. How to resolve this issue? Do we need to use list header for displaying the paragraph instead of textview? Please help me regarding this....

Thanks in Advance

MyCode:

```
public class test extends Activity  {

        public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> paragraphlist = Para.stringList1;
        public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> alloptionlist = Para.stringList3;

        ArrayList<String> arr1;

        static  List<paragraphlist > listOfparagraphs = new ArrayList<paragraphlist >();
        String paradescp,quest;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.thelist);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.paradesc);
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listlist);

            arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<paragraphlist.size();i++){
            arr1 = paragraphlist .get(i)    ;
            System.out.println("here arr1 "+arr1);
            paradescp = arr1.get(4);
                quest = arr1.get(2);
                tv.setText(paradescp);
                listOfparagraphs .add(new paragraphlist(quest));
            }
            System.out.println("out here arr1 "+listOfparagraphs .size());
            lvAdapter adapter = new lvAdapter(this,listOfparagraphs );
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try putting your textview in a scroll view and listview after scroll view,giving both layout_weight=1?

Comment: Hi can we keep like that? Is that correct procedure? If so I will do like that...Please let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a seperate layout, inflate it and add it to the ListView using `addHeaderView()`

```
 View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
 listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

[`Here`](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a complete example for the same.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response....it worked fine...But I have small doubt...I kept an image on the top in header layout..when I am scrolling the page the image is also scrolling ...how to fix the image to top and scroll the remaining page content?

Comment: If you want Image should not scroll you should not add the image to the header, just make image static above the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scrolling on a `ListView`, use it as the only element in your activity. Scrolling `Listview`s do not work well if they are added to another layout.

Then add Headers and Footers using `addHeader()` and `addFooter` from the ListView.